# How convert Int32* to Int32?

Tags: c++

This is my code

```
int32 *iPos;
status =scriptData.GetInt32(iPos);
int32 position=iPos;
```

But it occur  `error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from 'int32 *' to 'int32'`

How convert Int32* to Int32?

Comment: Any decent C++ book/tutorial will tell you how. You dereference the pointer : `int position = *iPos;`.

Comment: Had you tried `position = *iPos;`?

Comment: Convert? Are you really sure that's what you want to do? I get the impression you aren't understanding what pointers do.... (or are using the word 'convert' in a strange way) And are probably using `GetInt32` wrongly too.

Comment: Thanks all Hero Keyboards .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just dereference it:

```
int32 position = *iPos;
```

But the more elegant version is to use the `&` operator to get a pointer to `position`:

```
int32 position;
status = scriptData.GetInt32(&position);
```

Comment: thank you: int32 position;
status = scriptData.GetInt32(&position);

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should do this :

```
int32 position = *ipos;
```

(*ipos) return the value of your pointer, (&ipos) return the address of your pointer